# Why does this code not get colored in python?

Tags: python, colors

When ever I use the code:

```
import sys
from termcolor import colored, cprint

text = colored('Hello, World!', 'red', attrs=['reverse', 'blink'])
print(text)
cprint('Hello, World!', 'green', 'on_red')
```

I get the output of :

```
[5m[7m[31mHello, World![0m
[41m[32mHello, World![0m
```

Why am I getting this output?

Comment: What is your OS and what shell/console/IDE etc. are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 and python shell 3.7 from python.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is showing just fine in my terminal. Where are you running this code?

ANSI colors are used in termcolor with the windows terminal, you'll need to also import colorama to  make that work.

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
```

And then use above code of yours.
For more : https://pypi.org/project/colorama/

Comment: do i need to do `pip install colorama`

Comment: Yes. Do that before importing. I have attached a link for more information on colorama.